# No analytic function in $\{|z|<1\}$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)|\ge 1+|z|^2$. Proof strategy

Tags: complex-analysis

Show there is no analytic function in $\{|z|<1\}$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)|\ge 1+|z|^2$. I guess something went wrong along the way and I would like your assistance.

$f$ does'nt get a maximum in the domain, because if it did, it would be constant in the domain, meaning $|f(z)|=1\ge 1+|z|^2$ which doesn't hold for all z. Since $f$ isn't zero in the domain, ${1\over f}$ is analytic in the domain. but $|{1\over f(z)}|\le {1\over 1+|z|^2}\le 1={1\over f(0)}$, which indicates a local maximum making ${1\over f}$ constant, contradiction the fact the $f$ isn't. What am I really lacking here?

Comment: You seem to be missing some words. "contradiction the fact the $f$ isn't".

The only thing I can point out is that you don't need to discuss anything about $f$ obtaining a max; all that matters is $1/f$.

Comment: In fact, it isn't, by the given data, which pretty much means I did nothing.

Comment: I edited, although this proof fails.

Comment: Your proof does not fail; you observed that $1/f$ is analytic and $|1/f|$ obtains a strict max at $z = 0$, which is impossible.

Comment: So is that all there is to it?

Comment: I wish I could tell who serially downvotes my questions unexplained. That's really not fair and defaming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is alright. You assumed the existence of a function $f$ with the given properties and derived a contradiction.