# Prove that a function which is analytic in unit circle and satisfies $f(0)=1$ and $f(z) \ge 1 + |z|^ 2$ doesn't exist

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, cauchy-integral-formula

Let $G=\{ z \mid |z| < 1\} $. Show there are not function such that $f \in A(G)$ and $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)| \ge 1 + |z| ^ 2$

So I assume by contradiction that there is such function $f$. I thought to start using Cauchy's formula and I get 
$$ \int_{|z|= 1} \frac{f(z)}{z} \,\mathrm dz= f(0) = 1$$

It seems that I should somehow use the maximum principle, but since here $f$ is greater than something, I am not really sure how.

Help would be appreciated

Comment: Does $A(G)$ denote the analytic functions on $G$?

Comment: Yes, this is what it means

Comment: $f(z)\ge1+|z|^2$ doesn't make sense; $f$ is complex valued. Did you mean $|f(z)|?$

Comment: Possible duplicate of [No analytic function in $\{|z|<1\}$ such that $f(0)=1$ and $|f(z)|\ge 1+|z|^2$. Proof strategy](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1568366/no-analytic-function-in-z1-such-that-f0-1-and-fz-ge-1z2)

Comment: Please change $f(z)$ to $|f(z)|$ in the inequality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose there is such an $f.$ Then the inequality $|f(z)|\ge 1+|z|^2$ implies $f$ is never $0$ in $G.$ Thus $1/f\in A(G).$ Now apply the maximum principle to see

$$1=\left |\frac{1}{f(0)}\right| \le \max_{|z|=1/2}\left |\frac{1}{f(z)}\right |$$ $$ = \max_{|z|=1/2}\frac{1}{|f(z)|} \le \frac{1}{1+(1/2)^2} = \frac{4}{5},$$

a contradiction.

Comment: Well it seems using $\frac {1}{f} $ is helpful in many times. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

This follows from the open mapping theorem. If such an $f$ existed, its image would have to contain an open disk around $1$ (since $f(0)=1$) and thus, in particular, a point $w$ with $|w| < 1$; but $|f(z)|\ge 1+|z|^2 \ge 1$ for all $z\in G$.

Comment: Could you quote the theorem?

Comment: @GabiG https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_mapping_theorem_(complex_analysis)

Comment: Is there a way to do it without this theorem? I didn't learn it in class